# Add text and image to UITextField right side

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitextfield

How do I add Text and Image on right of the `UITextField`.
I have a `UITextField` which will initially have a text/label at right of it and when user click on the button the same `textField` will now have text + image to the right of `UITextField`

Image can be added like this but what about the text/label and both ?

```
txtField.rightViewMode = .always
txtField.rightView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "selectdrop"))
```

Comment: use **UIVIEW** and place **textField** and **UIImage** in your **UIView**

Comment: Are you sure that "selectdrop" is the right name?

Comment: @AhmadF my code works fine but it is only for image. I want to show label and image both

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For that you can create on `UIView` instance and add the `UILabel` and `UIImageView` inside it then finally set that view as `rightView` of `textField`. Some thing like below.

```
let rightView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40))

let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 40))
label.text = "Text"
label.textColor = UIColor.red
label.textAlignment = .center

let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "selectdrop")
rightView.addSubview(label)
rightView.addSubview(imageView)

txtField.rightView = rightView
txtField.rightViewMode = .always
```

Comment: Image and text is getting overlapped. Tried to fixed it but still.

Comment: What if the screen size increases? Will to increase too?

Comment: @Mr.Bista Yes it should. Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: @Nitesh Can you show the screen shot of your problem.

Comment: @Nitesh Its simple your label width is small and text is big, you need to first increase the rightView width and then increase the label width at last set the imageView `x` to the label width.

Comment: @NiravD Yes even after doing that it collapse.

Comment: @NiravD Still no. But I shifted Label `x: -15` this worked it for me.

Comment: @Nitesh Ok great :)